# Converting mod_rewrite rules to nginx config - unexpected download instead of rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am messing around with nginx and trying to translate mod_rewrite rules to nginx. So far I have been using the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 403 /HttpUnauthorized
ErrorDocument 404 /HttpNotFound

# Remove Trailing Slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [NC,R=301,L]

# Removes index.php from URLs (actually this happens everywhere!)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) $1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

A tool I found online suggested the following output:

```
error_page 404 /HttpNotFound;
error_page 403 /HttpUnauthorized;

location / {
    if ($request_method != "POST") {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 redirect;
    }
    rewrite (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 redirect;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=/$1 break;
    }
}
```

And (maybe it is important as well) for PHP I am using this call:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

---

Requesting `http://localhost/Foo` is actually downloading the raw `index.php` source file but requesting `http://localhost/index.php?q=/Foo` opens the respective site in the browser properly with the expected output. What is actually wrong with my config?

---

#### Some issues after experimenting with custom rules

Since it turned out that the rules from the tool were pretty bad I started with a basic

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

The query string I used to get via `$_REQUEST['q']` could now be read using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. So I attempted to add the removal of trailing slashes using

```
rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

unfortunately this both works and does not work at the same time in my **specific** setup. I am running nginx in a Docker container hence the server is internally listening on port 80 while being exposed on port 8082. Since nginx thinks it is running on port 80 (even though I am requesting via `http://localhost:8082/Foo/`) it rewrites to `http://localhost/Foo`. Is there any way to handle this other than making the server listen to the correct port in the first place?

Comment: I am not sure to properly understand your comment regarding the port. Do you mean that redirections doesn't work anymore? Or that nginx somehow get mixed up, thinking that the query is actually intended for another virtual host?

Comment: @jwatkins When I browse to `http://localhost:8082/Foo/` I expect to get redirected to `http://localhost:8082/Foo` but I am redirected to `http://localhost/Foo/` which is identical to `http://localhost:80/Foo/`. Since I have a `listen 80` in the config this is happening as the server apparently isn't noticing I am accessing it from another port that is exposed from Docker. Therefore I was just considering to handle the more difficult rewrites/redirects in Php itself.

Comment: Ok, there's two points here...  First, you should not use a redirection to remove the trailing slash. This cause an additional full round trip penalty on page load time, and can be avoided. Second, I remember having resolved a very similar issue by adding an extra `listen 80xx` statement; you do not need to expose these ports on the docker container, but if I remember correctly, nginx gets fooled by this and stops trying to fix port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PHP file gets downloaded, it basically indicates that the *.php location doesn't get matched in that case. So why isn't?

The `rewrite ... break` rule tells nginx to stop processing the current set of rewrite rules, but the control remain inside the current location block. This is not what you want: you actually want nginx to reevaluate the location based on the new uri you computed.

Try replacing the `break` keyword by `last`. This will tells nginx that it has to start a new round, searching for the modified uri.

**Update**

Before going any further, try this very simple configuration:

```
location / {
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Comment: Now I am not getting a download but a 404 error (which actually gets displayed correctly thus `/HttpNotFound` is correctly rewritten to `/index.php?q=/HttpNotFound` internally!) since `http://localhost/Foo` doesn't seem to be internally rewritten to the expected `http://localhost/index.php?q=/Foo`. I guess I will have to manually write the rewrite rules to match my former Apache rules.

Comment: Actually, I would never recommend the use of an automated tool to convert Apache rewrite rules to nginx configuration. Most Apache configurations, even some that includes extensive rewrite rules set, can be replaced by very simple, easy to understand nginx configuration. The `try_files` directive, in particular, is a very powerful tool, that should generally be tried before anything else.

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that one line is already responsible for most of my stuff however I have another strange issue I will edit into my question in a few moments.

Comment: Also, the `if` directive is very unpopular among the nginx community (see https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). There are very strong reasons to avoid it as much as possible; it is a shame that automated conversion tools suggest configurations composed around that structure.

Comment: Thanks for your input thus far - I have actually used the simple configuration as mentioned in my edit. Unfortunately I am struggling a bit with my container configuration and management of ports. Nevertheless it seems that writing proper rewrite rules for nginx is way easier.

Comment: Actually, I could just use the single `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;` line and handle everything else in my Php code which would simplify the configuration anyways.